# Apache Solr Search Can Index But Not Search

Tags: drupal, solr

I'm having a weird problem, where I can connect to Solr, and index the site (I can search on the Solr Admin area for the indexed content, and it works), but when I search in Drupal, I get the error:

The Apache Solr search engine is not available. Please contact your site administrator.

Does anyone know why this would happen? I can clear connect to Apache Solr, so I'm not sure why this would happen. The error I get in the logs is
"0" Status: Communication Error

which is in no way helpful to me.

Comment: Was my answer good to solve your problem..??..if yes, then accept it..!!

Comment: If you found my answer useful..do upvote it...and then accept it ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code like this in service.php:

```
$response = new Apache_Solr_Response(@file_get_contents($url, 
false, $this->_postContext), $http_response_header);
```

To be able to use `file_get_contents()` in PHP,
the "**allow_url_fopen**" directive must be enabled.
May be your server did not do that.

Try this :

```
- Creating php.ini
- Fill it with these lines:
[PHP]
allow_url_fopen = On
```